# Eureka multiple instance Feign clients. Dynamically target specific instance

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix-feign

I am running Eureka with multiple instances of multiple Feign clients all load balanced with Ribbon. I have a situation whereby I need to target a request to a particular Feign client instance. Is it possible to set the instance by say instance Id and guarantee the call will be made to that instance?